# How to scrape .aspx site in R and change dropdown box values

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest, scrape

I would like to scrape the table in the following link: https://www.fangraphs.com/dailyprojections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=sabersim&team=0&lg=all&players=0&sort=18,d

I am able to get the results using rvest package, but only the first 30 that are displayed on the first page. How can I change the "page size" dropdown to increase to 1000 so that I can get all results?

This is the code that I have tried so far, but I am assuming this is not an HTML table, so a different method will need to be used.

```
library(rvest)
url <-  "https://www.fangraphs.com/dailyprojections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=sabersim"

url1 <- url
pgsession <- html_session(url1)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <-set_values(pgform, "DFSBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$PageSizeComboBox" = "1000")

a <- submit_form(session = pgsession, form=filled_form)
get_table <- a %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
.[[4]] %>%
html_table(header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please write the function calls as they appear. Are you sure `Html_table` exists in `rvest`? R is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes, html_table exists. Sorry for the typo